# Converting realtime video into an array using Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, real-time, frame, video-processing

I have a problem with realtime video processing in Matlab for gesture recognition. I have tried

```
n = 20; % 'n' is the number of frames i want to capture

%preallocating frame()
for i=1:n
    frame(:,:,:,i) = getsnapshot(vid);
end
```

But when I try to access each array using the following loop

```
for i=1:n
    image=frame(:,:,:,i);
    y=imresize(image,[50, 50]);
    b=rgb2gray(y);

    %%processing for features
end
```

the array `b` always contains the value `1`. Is there anything wrong with my implementation? Do I always have to convert each frame into an image file?

Comment: If Falimond's answer fixed your problem, accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely in the only code snippet you haven't provided :P

When you preallocate the frame array make sure it's something like:

```
frame = zeros(720,1280,3,N,'uint8');
```

Only calling zeros() with no cast will allocate it as an array of doubles. It seems that using 'int8' also gives unwanted results. Maybe this is different on your machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It works now :) i've preallocated as frame = zeros(720,1280,3,n); before